# Martial maneuvers in an organised, easy to read form?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat-maneuver, tome-of-battle

So, the question came up during the making of a swordsage, and the need to check if the maneuvers chosen can actually be acquired due to prerequisites.

Is there anything, in pdf or online form, that has the maneuvers organised in a reasonable way, one that does not give you headaches for just trying to find a meneuver? I have the book and the maneuver cards, but they are still somehow troublesome to the brain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the Tome of Battle For Dummies handbook provides:

- A [list](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19871270/Tome_of_Battle_for_Dummies&post_num=8#338388910) of maneuvers organized by prereqs and level.
- A [list](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=357.msg6908#msg6908) of choice maneuvers

Comment: This saved me from a ****load of scrolling up and down, up and down. Thanks.

Comment: The first link is down - unfortunately!

Answer (score 5):

This [Unofficial Tome of Battle Tools](http://www.tob-tools.net/search/) page contains a search engine for all maneuvers in the Tome of Battle. "Number of prerequisites" is one of the possible filters. Full maneuver texts are accessible.

It also contains indexes [by alphabetical order](http://www.tob-tools.net/maneuvers-alphabetical/), [discipline](http://www.tob-tools.net/maneuvers-by-discipline/) and [maneuver level](http://www.tob-tools.net/maneuvers-by-level/).

Disclosure: I wrote the website.